# Django URL names use in Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

Right now in my templates I hardcore the links in my navigation like the following:

```
`base.html`

<a href="/about">About</a>
<a href="/contact">Contact</a>
<!-- etc -->
```

In my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/about.html'), name='about'),
    url(r'^contact/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='pages/contact.html'), name='contact'),
 )
```

Is there a way that in my `base.html` file reference the urlpatterns from `urls.py` so that anytime I change those, it reflects everywhere across my pages and templates?? Something like

```
<!-- what I would like to do -->
<a href="{{ reference_to_about_page }}">About</a>
<a href="{{ reference_to_contact_page }}">About</a>
```

Comment: Read the docs properly before putting questions on SO ... its clearly mentioned here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Did the answer helped or there is smth to improve? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

This is why [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag was invented:

> Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name)
>   matching a given view function and optional parameters.
>
> If you’re
>   using named URL patterns, you can refer to the name of the pattern in
>   the url tag instead of using the path to the view.

This basically means that you can use url names configured in the `urlpatterns` in the `url` tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
<a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
```

This gives you more flexibility. Now any time the actual url of `about` or `contact` page changes, templates would "catch up" the change automagically.

Answer (score 3):

Use Django's `url` template tag (docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)) with your named url pattern.

Example:

```
<a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
<a href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact</a>
```

Note that the name you put in `' '` will be the `name` of the particular url pattern in your `urls.py`. Also, if this is the `urls.py` file in an app (that is, it gets routed initially from the base `urls.py`), you'll need to include the namespacing of the app.

Comment: For someone that does not know, to include the namespacing, you need to put ":" like:
<a href="{% url 'pages:root' %}">; pages is the name of your app and root, the named name of your view (ex: name="root") in urlspatterns.